# How to get the ID of inserted object when using AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, repository

I had to create an account to ask this question because I couldn't find the right way to do this. The only thing that comes close is [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364240/android-room-get-the-id-of-new-inserted-row-with-auto-generate), but it doesn't go all the way and I'm still stuck. Here we go...

I'm trying to build an app following as much of the [Architecture Components principles](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).
I'm currently trying to add a row in one of my database table, and get the ID of this row in return, to then insert a row in another table, with a reference to the first one.

I've created my database object:

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index("id")})
public class Search {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) private int id;
...
```

And the corresponding DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface SearchDao {

    @Insert
    long insert(Search search);
...
```

As you can see, my DAO returns a long with the created ID. This is the behavior which was pointed out in the question I linked before, and documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert).

Since I'm following Android Architecture Components principles, I'm using a Repository class to do all my database related work. In this Repository, I've created a public method to insert a new object, which is creating and executing an AsyncTask to do the work:

```
public class Repository {
    public void insertSearch(Search search) {
        new insertSearchAsyncTask(this.mSearchDao).execute(search);
    }

...
    private static class insertSearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Search, Void, Long> {

        private SearchDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertSearchAsyncTask(SearchDao dao) {
            this.mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(final Search... params) {
            long id = this.mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
            return id;
        }
}
```

I know I can use the onPostExecute(long id) method to do stuff with the result of the doInBackground method, but this onPostExecute method cannot return anything to the insertSearch method, where I created the AsyncTask and executed it.

I know need to change the return type of my insertSearch method to long. However if I want to have something to return, I need to get the result of the execution of the AsyncTask. **How can I do that?**

I've tried [this (according to the validated answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458258/return-a-value-from-asynctask-in-android/26820666#26820666):

```
public class Repository {
    private long result_id = 0;
    public long insertSearch(Search search) {
        new insertSearchAsyncTask(this.mSearchDao).execute(search);
        return result_id;
    }

    private class insertSearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Search, Void, Long> {

        private SearchDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertSearchAsyncTask(SearchDao dao) {
            this.mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(final Search... params) {
            long id = this.mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long search_id) {
            result_id = search_id;
        }

    }
}
```

**But this feels very *very* wrong.** I had to make the insertSearchAsyncTask class not-static, and I have to store the result of the insert in an attribute of my Repository.
I'm hoping there is a better/correct way of doing this.

I've also looked at other suggested answers on the link above, especially one about Delegates, but this doesn't suit my need as I need the method insertSearch to return the result, not another one called by the AsyncTask when it finishes.

I hope I've explained my problem clearly enough.
Any idea anyone?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Did you find out something, i need the same as you did.