# How to get OnConflictStrategy return value from DAO

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I am using Room Persistence Library. The operation works as expected. But how do I get `onConflict` value from DAO back from calling method. I get the following error

```
error: Not sure how to handle the insert method's return type.
```

**Update**
After I change return type from Integer to long, I get this error

```
Not sure how to handle update method's return type. Currently the supported return types are void, int or Int.
```

In **DAO.java**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    long insert(UserEntity userEntity);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long update(UserEntity userEntity);
}
```

In **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(UserEntity... userEntities) {
    long result = userDao.insert(userEntities[0]);
    if(result == OnConflictStrategy.ABORT){
        result = userDao.update(userEntities[0]);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364240/android-room-get-the-id-of-new-inserted-row-with-auto-generate

Comment: @kdblue i tried changing from Integer to Long as suggested, it showing error above. See my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `ConflictStrategy.ABORT` Room will throw a `SQLiteConstraintException`. You can catch that to fit your use case.

The compilation error you are getting is due to the fact `@Insert` operations can return `long`, `long[]` or `void` only. `Integer` will not do.

`@Update` will return the number of rows updated by the query. This method will return an `int` or `void`. Doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: When i change Integer to long, i get this. error: Not sure how to handle update method's return type. Currently the supported return types are void, int or Int.

Comment: Are you using Kotlin or Java? `Int` has no meaning in Java.

Comment: i am using java

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html . This clearly states rowIds are signed 64 bit integers..

Comment: Are you sure u are using `long` and not `Long`?

Comment: `Not sure how to handle update method's return type. Currently the supported return types are void, int or Int.` This say `update method's` return type. Please post the `@Update` contract

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194413/discussion-between-kirpal-singh-and-arka-prava-basu).

Comment: I have updated my code to include Update interface method

Comment: Answer updated. Update method will return the no of rows updated with is limited by  32 bit integer in SQLite

Answer (score 1):

**Insert**
If the @Insert method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a long, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return long[] or List instead.

**Update**
Although usually not necessary, you can have this method return an int value instead, indicating the number of rows updated in the database.

After reading multiple time, i understood the methods are returning number of records instead of error code. Anyway my question regarding how  OnConflictStrategy values are read or used is still unanswered

Comment: U cant "read" its value. As answered if ABORT it will throw an SQLiteConstraintException. Source: https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/room-and-conflict-resolution

Need to find out of the other states.