# Automatically updating primary key in newly inserted Room Entity

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-jetpack

When you add a freshly created object in Room, with auto generation of the
primary key, the newly created object keeps it’s undefined primary key. This
proves inconvenient when you need to modify this object and persist the
changes.

Let’s take an example.

### Entity Dao

So, let’s create a `User` whose `id` is auto-generated.

```java
@Entity()
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public User(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    // Other methods, especially getter and setter for each field

    // …
}
```

We have the following Dao:

```java
public class UserDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(User user);

    @Update
    int update(User user);

    // …
}
```

We interract through the following Repository:

```java
public class Repository {
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDao.insert(user);
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        userDao.update(user);
    }

    // …
}
```

### Inserting and updating an Entity

So, now if we do this, `user` will not be updated, because `User.id` will stay at 0 and `Update` annotation [updates the row only if the primary key already exists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Update).

```java
Repository r = new Repository();
User user = new User("me@my.email");
r.addUser(user);
user.setEmail("new@user.email");
```

### Proposed solution

To tackle this issue, we could change the `addUser` method of the `Repository` to update id after insertion.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364240/android-room-get-the-id-of-new-inserted-row-with-auto-generate) gave me the following idea:

```java
public class Repository {
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        long rowid = userDao.insert(user);
        user.setId(userDao.getIdFromRowid(rowid));
    }

    // …
}
```

With this Dao (note that `insert` returns a `long` instead of `void`):

```java
public class UserDao {
    @Insert
    long insert(User user);

    @Update
    int update(User user);

    @Query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE ROWID = :rowid")
    int getIdFromRowid(long rowid);

    // …
}
```

Would this be an acceptable solution in the Android Jetpack paradigm? Do you
see any pitfall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Proposed solution is acceptable, you can get the inserted id from the Room DB then set to your object reference back. So you could perform update and delete operations. The other think you could explorer and use is LiveData on Select query, which will give you update data in callback whenever it will be change in Room DB. But, it depends upon you logic. 
Example :

```
@Query("SELECT * from test_tbl")
 LiveData<List<Model>> getTestData();
```