# Android Room force rewrite property by autoincrement value

Tags: android, kotlin, dao

I have a standart long field

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 val id:Long
```

But it is filled in the process and has a random value. If I try to add it to the database through the DAO, then the id is not overwritten by autoGenerate sqlite engine

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
 fun insert(i:MyTypeObject)
```

If I do this type field nullable its does not work too

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 val id:Long?
```

There is a way that any value that would be in the id field is forcibly converted to autoincrement value in db?

I recive data from repository livedata. In viewmodel

```
private val db = CurrencyDatabase.getInstance(getApplication())
private val dao = db!!.nalDao()
private val service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)

  fun addBook(book: CurrencyItem)
{
    service.submit {
        dao.insert(book)
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that calls for the insert.

Comment: @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) fun insert(i:MyTypeObject)

Comment: Not the DAO, "But it is filled in the process" .. This one

Comment: i updated the question. Bottom method that i use

Comment: OK set the id to 0 before dao.insert(book)

Comment: You dont need one by one increment you need the id after the insert, having the id will allow you to do anything you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364240/android-room-get-the-id-of-new-inserted-row-with-auto-generate

Comment: i need force autoincrement

Comment: Why, do you need auto increment?

Comment: Thanks i found default solution. I need auto increment for easy data access. For example i write select which return last 5 rows, its very simple solution if autoincrement work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. By official documentaion "If the field type is long or int (or its TypeConverter converts it to a long or int), Insert methods treat 0 as not-set while inserting the item. " You must add 0 to id field with autoincrement.

Also my problem was incorrect access to database data file. I use "Device file explorer" on Android stuidiо and "Save as" on right click menu. Its wrong way for SQL data debugging. Correct access to data its adb terminal shell. For example my OS Win10 and database file name = book.db, and datatable = nal

Open terminal

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
adb root
adb devices
```

My device was "emulator-5554" then

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
sqlite3
```

Inside sqlite shell

```
.open /data/data/com.example.scotland/databases/book.db
select * from nal;
```

If you cant find you database file. Try open

```
View->ToolWindows->Device File explorer.
```

There tree you ADB filesystem. You must open

```
data->data->YouProjectName->databases
```